# Can't create user using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I can't create user using jmeter on specific website: https://partner-test.smartcity.comarch.com/home . If I create user manually the user is added. On other websites everything goes smooth for me. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

[I added screen with jmeter's script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRklz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't correlate some required value located in:

- Path
- Header
- Or parameters of the request

This is usually done by extracting data using JMeter Extractors (see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to create variables from extracted data and then inject those in next requests using:

> ${variable Name}

Also ensure you added a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform correlation of the `p_auth` parameter which is being used in [Liferay](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token) application server for [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

So you need to:

1. Execute GET request to your `/web/guest/home` path
2. Extract `p_auth` token value (normally people use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for this)
3. Substitute hard-coded recorded value with the variable from step 2

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) for more information.

Comment: I've done that and I've checked that I get p_auth parameter correctly, but somehow it still doesn't work. I get 200 response code whereas I should get 302. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I've started server proxy HTTP from workbench and there are some difference between POST queries.  POST from proxy HTTP: POST https:// partner-test.smartcity.comarch.com/web/guest/home?p_auth=tCZVLhpu&p_p_id=b2pquickregistrationportlet_WAR_b2pquickregistrationportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1  , POST data : action=step2&postRedirectUrl=&email=alalalalon%40wp.pl&permissionTermsAndConditions=true&_permissionTermsAndConditions=on   and here is POST from chrome extension: POST https://partner-test.smartcity.comarch.com/web/guest/home