# Can we create bulk account with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, e-commerce, user-accounts

In order to do load testing of ecommerce site, i have to create 40 different accounts. So tried to do this with Jmeter and CSV upload and script is working fine without any error. But when I'm trying to logging with those accounts getting an error,"Invalid Username/Password."
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSOO1.png)

Comment: May you need to send GET and not POST?

Comment: updated the POST method to GET, but still user accounts not created.

Comment: Have a look at answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945893/cant-create-user-using-jmeter.